# Tabs output in PHP alone fine, in WP, they won't hide correctly

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm having a styling issue within WordPress that doesn't happen as a stand-alone PHP file.

[When viewed stand-alone, it looks great like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhKAF.png)

```
$tab_details = array();

echo "<ul class='tabx'>
        <li><input type='submit' value='Add checked' name='but0'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    ";

// My Actions tab 
echo "<li><a href='#' class='tabxlinks' id='htab1' onclick='openTab(event, \"tab1\")'>My Actions</a></li>";

// My Actions list of actions
$sqlsub = "select act_id, act_name from action inner join act_cat on acca_act_id = act_id where act_auth_id = ".$current_user->id." order by act_name";
$resultsub = $conn->query($sqlsub);

$tab_html = '<div id="tab1" class="tabxcontent"><table><tr><td></td><td style="text-align:left">Note</td></tr>';
while($rowsub = $resultsub->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tab_html .= '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkBLI(event);" name="chk1_'.$rowsub["act_id"].'" id="chk1_'.$rowsub["act_id"].'" value="'.$rowsub["act_id"].'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<label onclick="checkBLI(event);" for="chk1_'.$rowsub["act_id"].'">'.$rowsub["act_name"].'</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="txt1_'.$rowsub["act_id"].'" value="" onkeyup="fnKeyPress(this);" /></td></tr>';
}
$tab_html .= '</table></div>';
array_push($tab_details, $tab_html); 


/* database-driven tabs */
$sql = "select cat_id, cat_name_act_short from category c inner join cat_cat cc on c.cat_id = cc.child_cat_id where cc.parent_cat_id = 0 order by cat_name_act_short";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
    echo 'Error: ', $conn->error;
    exit();
} 

/* relevant actions of that tab */
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<li><a href='#' class='tabxlinks' onclick='openTab(event, \"tab".$row["cat_id"]."\")'>".$row["cat_name_act_short"]."</a></li>
            ";
    $tab_html = '<div id="tab'.$row["cat_id"].'" class="tabxcontent"><table>';
    $sqlsub = "select act_id, act_name from action inner join act_cat on acca_act_id = act_id where (act_public = 1 or act_auth_id = ".$current_user->id.") and acca_cat_id = ".$row["cat_id"]." order by act_name";
    $resultsub = $conn->query($sqlsub);
    while($rowsub = $resultsub->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tab_html .= '<tr><td style="text-align:left"><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkBLI(event);" name="chk'.$row["cat_id"].'_'.$rowsub["act_id"].'" id="chk'.$row["cat_id"].'_'.$rowsub["act_id"].'" value="'.$rowsub["act_id"].'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<label onclick="checkBLI(event);" for="chk'.$row["cat_id"].'_'.$rowsub["act_id"].'">'.$rowsub["act_name"].'</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="text-align:left"><input type="text" size="30" name="txt'.$row["cat_id"].'_'.$rowsub["act_id"].'" value="" onkeyup="fnKeyPress(this);" /></td></tr>
            ';
    }
    $tab_html .= '</table></div>

    ';
    array_push($tab_details, $tab_html); 
}
echo "</ul>";


/* output items underneath tab */
foreach ($tab_details as $output) {
    echo $output;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

When the same php file is included from within WordPress, it looks like:
[Same code within WP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVSMp.png)

I renamed the classes from TAB to TABX linking it might be a keyword already used in WP.

CSS code
    ul.tabx {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

```
/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tabx li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tabx li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tabx li a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tabx li a:focus, .active {background-color: #ccc;}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabxcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

Any help appreciated.  Thank you kindly.